# When should we call build/rebuild current project/solution and when to call clean solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I work with a team and sometimes get problems, eg missing a warning/error, when I don't rebuild the solution (I often call build solution only). Rebuild the solution help me get rid of those problems but take long times.

So, I want to know in which situations we should/shouldn't call rebuild as well as clean a solution/project?